# Can you dynamically set a Lightning:listViews list name?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightninglistview

I have an aura lightning component that has this lightning:listView component in it

```
<lightning:listView aura:id="StandardSelectionList"
    objectApiName="Standard__c"
    listName="{!v.listView}"
    rows="5"
    showSearchBar="false"
    showActionBar="false"
    enableInlineEdit="false"
    showRowLevelActions="false"
/>
```

The purpose of this is to select a specific list view based on the list view name returned from the controller into the aura attribute list view.

```
    <aura:attribute name="listView" type="string"/>
```

However, I am getting some strange behavior in which the list view always returns recently viewed instead of the name that is stored in the listView attribute. I have verified that the attribute is getting loaded with the correct list view names, as any place I output it directly it matches the developer name of the list view I am trying to access, but it does not seem to be making it into the list view name.

I have also found that if I set a default value of the attribute, it is able to successfully load whatever list view I set the default value to, even if that is different than what is being returned by the controller and displayed elsewhere that I access the attribute.

This leaves me wondering if there is some kind of issue that makes it impossible to set a listView component from a list name stored in an attribute that is returned by the controller, or if I just need to change how I am rendering this component so that it does not attempt to render until after the controller has returned the correct values. Does anyone know if this is in fact possible, and if so what I might be needing to do differently?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer is yes, kind of. For some reason the list view was rendering before the listView attribute was populated. The solution is to just add an

```
<aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.listView != null}">
```

tag around the list view, which seems to cause it to wait to be populated until the attribute is properly populated, which in turn causes it to show the correct list view.